# When typing "localhost" in the address bar, I want to see a directory of files/folders

Tags: apache

I recently installed XAMPP.  I notice that when I type 'localhost' in the address bar of my browser, it shows a nice XAMPP welcome page.  But I wish I could figure out how to show a directory of files and folders in my htdocs.  I've seen this work on my old stack - 'parent directory', etc.

I've been digging around my httpd.conf file, and have found things on Google about AllowOverride, etc.  Other sources say I should write a .htaccess file, but I can't get clarity on how to tweek my settings somehow to make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on your directory listing in apache configuration filehttpd.conf

For example  if you projects are in /var/www/html, edit httpd.conf to add

```
<Directory /var/www/html >
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Following this, restart the httpd service